# Push an item into an array, only if no items match today's date - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've been writing this pretty simple `angularjs` function that looks over an array, and if there are any items with a date matching today's date, it will not push a new item into the array.

I can see that it's a bit messy, and I have a feeling there may be a way simpler way to achieve this - I know this isn't a super clear question, but would just love some guidance and tips on how to clean this function up!

When I move the `.push()` call inside the loop, I cannot get the item to be pushed in, and what I want to achieve is - if there are any items in the array with a `date` that matches today, I do not want to push that item in, rather just break with an alert or something similar.

Thanks for any guidance!

```
$scope.historicalDailyPercentages = [];

$scope.finaliseDay = function(percentComplete) {
        alert("You're finalising this day with a percentage of: " + percentComplete);
        var today = new Date();

      //Confirm that nothing has alreayd been posted for today

      for (var i = $scope.historicalDailyPercentages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if($scope.historicalDailyPercentages[i].date == today) {
          console.log("we got a hit!" + $scope.historicalDailyPercentages[i].date);
        }
       else {
           $scope.historicalDailyPercentages.push({percent:percentComplete,  date:today}); //This line doesn't push the item in, but if I include this line at the top of the function, the item is successfully pushed in. 
       }

      };

      console.log($scope.historicalDailyPercentages);



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
$scope.finaliseDay = function(percentComplete) {
    alert("You're finalising this day with a percentage of: " + percentComplete);
    var today = new Date();
    var alreadyPresent = $scope.historicalDailyPercentages.some(function (item) { 
        return item.date.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
               item.date.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
               item.date.getDate() === today.getDate();
    });

    //Confirm that nothing has alreayd been posted for today
    if (!alreadyPresent) {
        $scope.historicalDailyPercentages.push({
            percent: percentComplete,
            date: today
        });
    }

    console.log($scope.historicalDailyPercentages);
}
```

Comment: Oh, man that was way cleaner thanks! I just realised one thing though - it lets me push multiple entries for the same day, given the timestamp is technically a few seconds later. Could you help me run that match based on the day?

Comment: Check out AngularJS date filter. You can easily convert timestamp to any number of format to validate against...